# scikit-learn 16: gbrt-tutorial has njobs>1 failure

Tags: python-2.7, multiprocessing, scikit-learn

Thanks and kudos to all who support the scikit-learn effort.

gbrt-tutorial ran fine this morning before noon time upgrade described below. gbrt-tutorial issue occurs in cell 14, re: grid search. After upgrade cell will not run if njobs greater than 1.

Looks like a failed assert statement somewhere in the deep code (see Traceback below).

Previously updated Anaconda install within last two months; did so again mid-day today (which left me with scikit-learn version 15.2, as before upgrade). Then did conda upgrade scikit-learn which installed 16.0. All seemed to be well until njobs issue. (Running Windows 7/64-bit; 8 cpus.)

This is more of a notice than a call for help; problem could be in other parts of Anaconda upgrade. I can do roll back and re-test, but no time right now. However, any thoughts/wisdom are certainly welcome.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 380, in main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 488, in prep
are
    assert main_name not in sys.modules, main_name
AssertionError: **main**

Comment: Problem is wider than gbrt-tutorial. Also occurs in short code
from sklearn import svm, grid_search, datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()
parameters = {'kernel':('linear', 'rbf'), 'C':[1, 10]}
svr = svm.SVC()
clf = grid_search.GridSearchCV(svr, parameters, n_jobs=2)
clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)

Comment: Can you say which code / example failed? On windows, you need to protect any multiprocessing with ``if __name__ == "__main__"`` that was true before and after the upgrade.